# Read structured file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with data similar to this:

```
[START]
Name  = Peter
Sex  = Male    

Age  = 34
Income[2020]  = 40000
Income[2019]  = 38500  
[END]

[START]
Name  = Maria
Sex  = Female    

Age  = 28
Income[2020]  = 43000
Income[2019]  = 42500 
Income[2018]  = 40000 
[END]

[START]
Name  = Jane
Sex  = Female    

Age  = 41
Income[2020]  = 60500
Income[2019]  = 57500 
Income[2018]  = 54000 
[END]
```

I want to read this data into a pandas dataframe so that at the end it is similar to this

```
Name   Sex        Age        Income[2020]   Income[2019]   Income[2018]
Peter  Male       34           40000          38500            NaN
Maria  Female     28           43000          42500            40000
Jane   Female     41           60500          57500            54000
```

So far, I wasn't able to figure out if this is a standard data file format (it has some similarities to JSON but is still very different).
Is there an elegant and fast way to read this data to a dataframe?

Comment: I dont think this format is a common format, so you should probably read it like a normal file, parse it separately, and load that into your DF.

Comment: In research data, it does exist. My research data are time series. Each block starts with ITEMS: TIMESTEP.

Answer (score 3):

Elegant I do not know, but easy way, yes. Python is very good at parsing simple formatted text.

Here, `[START]` starts a new record, `[END]` ends it, and inside a record, you have `key = value` lines. You can easily build a custom parser to generate a list of records to feed into a pandas DataFrame:

```
inblock = False
fieldnames = []
data = []
for line in open(filename):
    if inblock:
        if line.strip() == '[END]':
            inblock = False
        elif '=' in line:
            k, v = (i.strip() for i in line.split('=', 1))
            record[k] = v
            if not k in fieldnames:
                fieldnames.append(k)
    else:
        if line.strip() == '[START]':
            inblock = True
            record = {}
            data.append(record)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=fieldnames)
```

`df` is as expected:

```
    Name     Sex Age Income[2020] Income[2019] Income[2018]
0  Peter    Male  34        40000        38500          NaN
1  Maria  Female  28        43000        42500        40000
2   Jane  Female  41        60500        57500        54000
```